# ASR9001 Nv Satellite configuration

Tags: cisco-asr

I've read on CCO that a host which is part of a simple ring configuration can only be part of a single dual-home pairing.. So to confirm, a topology as seen below is not supported?

Thank you..

Rkirby

```
           Simple Ring 1
           9Kv——9Kv--—9Kv
          /              \
         /                \
  ASR9001                  ASR9001
         \                /
          \              /
           9Kv——9Kv—--9Kv
            Simple Ring 2
```